# filter and extract rcorr result

Tags: r, filter, correlation, error-correction

I calculated correlation for coding-ncoding by rcorr. Now I want to filter and extract the result by this code but there is an error. Why does the code have a problem?

**Code:**

```
library(Hmisc)

coef_BS<- matrix(data = res5$r, nrow =20 ,ncol=20)
pval_BS<- matrix(data = res5$P, nrow =20 ,ncol=20)
for(i in 1:20)
{
  for (j in 1:20)
  {
    if (i>=j)
    {
      rcor_out<-rcorr(c.num[,i], c.nc.num[,j], type="spearman")
      coef_BS[i,j] <- rcor_out$r[1, 2]
      pval_BS[i,j] <- rcor_out$P[1, 2]
    }
  }
  print(i)
}
```

**The error is:**

```
Error in c.nc.num[, j] : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!, please mention the error from your output and for more pointers see [how to post a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: thank you.I edited my post.I am new in R so I can not understand the problem